# Single User mode can't be turned off and no users are connected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database that is in Single User Mode.  When I run this:

```
exec sp_dboption 'MyDb', 'single user', 'FALSE'
```

It fails, telling me that there is still a user connected.

But when I run both of these:

```
exec sp_who2


select d.name, d.dbid, spid, login_time, nt_domain, nt_username, loginame
  from sysprocesses p inner join sysdatabases d on p.dbid = d.dbid
 where d.name = 'MyDb'
```

I get no connections for MyDb.

How can this be, and how can I get my database out of single user mode?

Comment: you aren't the user are you..? Do USE master before ALTER DATABASE (the new way to do this)

Comment: No, me and my DBA made very sure that was not the case.  I closed everything down and we double checked all connections from my machine.  (Again, no connections show up.)

Comment: http://remidian.com/2008/01/remove-sql-server-database-from-single-user-mode/ This blogpost helped me fix my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user - or process-  is using multiple databases, sp_who2 can only report on one of the databases per spid.

Have you tried something like the following - it will rollback all transaction not completed:

ALTER DATABASE [mydb] set multi_user with rollback immediate

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that did not work either...

Comment: What was the error message? What do the SQL Server logs say? Does it say when the database went into single user mode?

Comment: Same error as I always get (The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.)  I am afraid I don't know where to look for the logs.  (I am not a real DBA, just a developer admining a development database.)

Comment: We were able to get it out of single user mode (finally) but it kept going right back in.  Finally I had the drop the database and re-create it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You won't see other folks connection unless you are sysadmin or have VIEW SERVER STATE permissions because of MetaData visibility

Anyway, force it like this with [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx)
Note: sp_dboption is deprecated, [back to SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933268%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```